# MongoDB very slow deletes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a small replica set of three mongod servers (16GB RAM each, at least 4 CPU cores and real HDDs) and one dedicated arbiter.  The replicated data has about 100,000,000 records currently.  Nearly all of this data is in one collection with an index on `_id` (the auto-generated Mongo ID) and `date`, which is a native Mongo date field.  Periodically I delete old records from this collection using the date index, something like this (from the mongo shell):

```
db.repo.remove({"date" : {"$lt" : new Date(1362096000000)}})
```

This does work, but it runs very, very slowly.  One of my nodes has slower I/O than the other two, having just a single SATA drive.  When this node is primary, the deletes run at about 5-10 documents/sec.  By using rs.stepDown() I have demoted this slower primary and forced an election to get a primary with better I/O.  On that server, I am getting about 100 docs/sec.

My main question is, should I be concerned?  I don't have the numbers from before I introduced replication, but I know the delete was much faster.  I'm wondering if the replica set sync is causing I/O wait, or if there is some other cause.  I would be totally happy with temporarily disabling sync and index updates until the delete statement finishes, but I don't know of any way to do that currently.  For some reason, when I disable two of the three nodes, leaving just one node and the arbiter, the remaining node is demoted and writes are impossible (isn't the arbiter supposed to solve that?).

To give you some indication of the general performance, if I drop and recreate the date index, it takes about 15 minutes to scan all 100M docs.

Comment: the reason you can't disable two of your four nodes is that there cannot be a primary without majority of the set available.  Why do you have four members, by the way?  You don't need an arbiter with three nodes in a replica set.

Comment: Gotcha - I only have four nodes at the moment because the 5th node is missing a hard drive and I removed it from the cluster :)  Ironically, I brought up an arbiter to help guarantee there would always be a winner in a master election.  Anyway, the arbiter is a little VM that I also use for other low overhead stuff like config servers in other sharding clusters.

Comment: you needed an arbiter when you had four nodes (to have five votes) but when you remove the fifth node from the replica set you should remove the arbiter as well, so that you will have three members left.

Comment: Thanks Asya, it didn't occur to me that the arbiter itself is what was causing a failed election.  Anyway, from what I understand, a single node will never elect itself because there is no way to guarantee that it's not itself isolated from the cluster.  I remember seeing a page on the Mongo site about isolated replica set members, I'll have to find it back again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because even though

```
db.repo.remove({"date" : {"$lt" : new Date(1362096000000)}})
```

looks like a single command it's actually operating on many documents - as many as satisfy this query.

When you use replication, every change operation has to be written to a special collection in the `local` database called `oplog.rs` - oplog for short.

The oplog has to have an entry for each deleted document and every one of those entries needs to be applied to the oplog on each secondary before it can also delete the same record.

One thing I can suggest that you consider is [TTL indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) - they will "automatically" delete documents based on expiration date/value you set - this way you won't have one massive delete and instead will be able to spread the load more over time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes a lot of sense.  I also did not know about TTL Indexes - looks like an awesome feature!

Comment: I'm not sure that this solution is accurate. In the Mongo docs at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/ it states, "On replica sets, the TTL background thread only deletes documents on the primary. However, the TTL background thread does run on secondaries. Secondary members replicate deletion operations from the primary." To that wouldn't that mean there is no difference in oplog performance with a TTL compared to a manual operation?

Comment: the difference is TTL thread runs every minute looking for documents to delete.  The user in this case was running a single huge delete to remove them all at once.  TTL just spreads the delete over longer period so you are doing smaller chunks each minute.  That's assuming that expiration is on a field that's "to the minute" accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Another suggestion that may not fit you, but it was optimal solution for me:

1. drop indeces from collection
2. iterate over all entries of collection and store id's of records to delete into memory array
3. each time array is big enough (for me it was 10K records), i removed these records by ids
4. rebuild indeces

It is the fastest way, but it requires stopping the system, which was suitable for me.