# MongoDB: Safely bulk delete millions of old Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm want to know your opinion about the following situation:

Giving the following mongo db collection:

COLLECTION SIZE:  192.87GB

TOTAL DOCUMENTS:  165.578.552

I want to delete documents older than a year from now. I have an estimated that it will be around a half of the collection, approx 80 million documents.

So basically I have 2 questions:

Is it safe to run a `count()` query to have the exact match before delete documents?

`...->count({timestamp: {$lt: '1534976762'}})`

Note: `timestamp` is not indexed, I've another field `time`, that's indexed, but I cannot make the query works yet with `time.sec`

[image]

And second, how many documents I can safely delete in a batch? I'm from MySQL world and not an Mongo expert so, maybe I'm taking to much precautions. This is a production database.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB very slow deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327504/mongodb-very-slow-deletes)

Comment: On a non-indexed field, it's not safe to do `count(...)` since it will do a collection scan. Do `db.collection.explain().count(...)` and check if it contains `COLLSCAN`. If it does (it should), then it's not safe.

Comment: Additionally, what is the output of `db.collection.getIndexes()` on that collection? How are you indexing the `time` field?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to bring down a secondary node and run the count on it, get the numbers, do the analysis and then perform the delete. Remember, deleting the documents will not release space back to OS. Instead, mongodb will reserve the space considering future growth

If you're planning to perform housekeeping on the collection, better copy the required documents to new collection and drop the existing one

Answer (score 2):

It may be faster to `find` the documents you want to keep copy them to a new collection and then drop the old collection.

To accurately count the documents in a collection you need to use [CountDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) as the older `count`command does not give an accurate count in all situations. As the previous author mentioned `countDocuments`on an unindexed field will do a collection scan which will impact database performance. Once you have your collection you can use [deleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db.collection.deleteMany) with the same query to to delete those documents.

To ensure that the counted documents and the deleted document set are guaranteed not to change you can run the `countDocuments` and `delete_many` inside a [transaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/).